# IE6 doesn't support jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, accordion

I am designing my new site, and accordion is the main part of my site.

It is working perfectly in IE7, IE8, Mozilla and Chrome.

It remains expanded in IE6 and will not work.

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
    jQuery('#portslid').accordion({     
        autoheight: false,          
        alwaysOpen:> false,         
        active: true,       
        animated: "bounceslide",        
    });             
});
```

I want accordion to expand during page load and after the load completes it should compact.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Simple answer: don't support IE6. Let the fools still using it suffer with a static/ugly/broken site.

Comment: is that "alwaysOpen:> false" typo just in your question or the code on your page?

Comment: IE hates trailing commas.  Remove the last comma (after `animated: "bounceslide"`).

Comment: Please please do not support IE6. You're not doing a favor to anyone by supporting it.

Comment: @MarcB In the real world that isn't always a viable option. I know of quite a few big companies that are stuck using that monstrosity because there is too much overhead involved in upgrading to a newer browser.

Comment: Even [Microsoft](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) is trying to get people to upgrade.

Comment: @scrappedcola: Then perhaps those big companies should pay their IT departments a bit more to get onto something more modern. They can pay for it from the savings of not being compromised as often.

Comment: @scrappedcola and those companies can do without accordians then.

Comment: @scrappedcola And those companies will never upgrade if we keep supporting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
jQuery().ready(function(){
  jQuery('#portslid').accordion({   
    autoheight: false,          
    alwaysOpen: false,      
    active: true,       
    animated: "bounceslide"   
  });               
});
</script>
```

Remove the trailing "," at the end of animated and it will probably be ok.

Comment: "it Worked" Thank You Very much.You peoples are great.i am really laughing at my self.how easy was that.Thanks Again

Comment: I've done this specific one myself before :-) You add another param after the animated then remove it but forget to remove the ",". It's something that starts prefix "," vs postfix "," arguments all the time at my Comp

Answer (score 1):

while I agree with @MarcB's comment, the issue is most likely the trailing comma in the configs object. those tend to throw IE for a loop.

also, if it isn't a typo here, the `:>` could be an issue, but that would be an issue in any browser.